# noise and echo in QuickBlox VideoChat in Angular

Tags: angular, networking, echo, quickblox, videocall

I have develop the videochat in Angular. I can refer Javascript SDK Sample. The sample is working fine. But when i developing the example in angular  I get a lot of noise and echo in addiction to the audio/video delay. Why is that so? And Also Same network local and remote peer was connected but in different network peers are not connected. What is the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the implementation of your own video stream with the help of the `<video/>` tag, please make sure that you have disabled the audio stream from this tag.

You can also apply constraints to the audio/video streams in order to resolve this case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints#track_constraints

How to set constraints:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints#applying_constraints

Here is some example:

```js
const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: true,
      noiseSuppression: true,
    },
      video: true
 }
    
session.getUserMedia(constraints, (err, stream) => {
})
```

As for the second issue, please note that we do not provide support with Angular as we don't have developers experienced in this framework. You can take our Javascript samples and compare them with your custom code.